# Can Waze cause the cell phone to overheat even after being closed?

Tags: overheating, motorola-moto-g

By closed I mean clicking "switch off" in notifications panel and closing it in "recent apps".

Waze consumes at most 20% of my battery during normal use but after turning it off, my cell phone keeps getting hotter for no apparent reason.

Things I tried:

- Turning it off and back on. It does cool down when it's off but after turning it back on the heating continues gradually.
- Using Juice Defender in agressive mode. No change.
- Troubleshooting with Watchdog Lite. The process consuming the most energy is Android System (around 10-15%).

I suspect Waze has something to do with this because the problem exists even when I only opened this app that day.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is No!. Waze is just an app, a piece of software and has no bearing on battery life or heat generation.

Heat is generated from devices within your phone running with too much power. Waze maybe the app that starts these devices going, but ultimately, it is the phones hardware that is causing the heat.

Screens generate a large amount of heat to provide the brightness needed, try reducing the brightness level on the screen. Also, the satellite tracking system may be needing more power if the signals being received are too small. some phones have a self boost amplifier and these can also burn battery power. Anything that runs these types of hardware would cause you phone to get hot, and lack of cooling would not help.

Most phones are designed now to be as thin and light as possible, this is done by sacrificing heatsinking (the designers assume the phone will only be used for short periods at a time).

Comment: Answering "no" to "can an app cause the cell phone to overheat" is drawing a distinction without a difference. If the app makes the CPU run at full power continuously, it'll make the phone heat up. The heat's physically coming from the CPU, but that doesn't mean the app's not responsible.

Answer (score 0):

Waze definitely not just causes my Samsung S3 to get hot, but always causes the phone to heat up wildly until it crashes due to extreme overheating.  I can get a maximum of 30 minutes out of it before my phone overheats and dies.  It's the only app that I've ever seen do that.  Also, it uses more power than my phone charger can provide, so the battery level drops consistently even when plugged in to a charger that can provide 2.1 amps.  I've had to stop using Waze.  Too bad, as it seems like a nice app, but I can't run something that's going to destroy my phone.